# Linearizing a first order ODE and classifying equilibrium points

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I was asked to linearize the first order ODE for an oscillating spring $$(x,v)^{'}=(v,-av^3-b(x^2-1))$$ where $a,b>0$.

Is it correct to simply find the jacobian of $(v, -av^3-b(x^2-1))$?

For the jacobian I got $$J=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-2bx&-3av^2\end{bmatrix}$$
After plugging in the critical points $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ my matrix became $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-2b&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\2b&0\end{bmatrix}$

After this, I used tried to find the eigenvalues by using the equations:

$\lambda^2-2b=0$ for $(1,0)$ and $\lambda^2+2b=0$ for $(-1,0)$.

By my calculations, $\lambda=\pm{\sqrt{2b}}$ for the point $(1,0)$ and $\lambda=\pm{\sqrt{-2b}}$ for the point $(-1,0)$.

This should mean $(1,0)$ is a saddle point while $(-1,0)$ is a an ellipse. This result does not seem intuitive though. Is there any point where I made a mistake? Should there not be a stable equilibrium for a spring?

Comment: Your work looks good. There may not be a stable equilibrium for your spring, but the "ellipse" or "center" is a reasonable orbit to be expected (no damping term).

Comment: Well, never say that equilibrium of nonlinear system is a center judging only by eigenvalues, it's wrong. But, in this case, you can prove that this is a center equilibrium: it can be done via symmetries or using the first integral (kind of idea that @Paichu meant noticing that there is no damping term). The description for symmetry method can be found for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577274/formal-proof-of-lyapunov-stability/1577548#1577548).

Comment: @Evgeny Your answer for the other question is really nice. :)

Comment: @Paichu Thank you! That was quite interesting problem to solve and I tried to write an entertaining solution  :)