# $ \dot x = y-a_0-a_1 x - a_2x^2$ , $\dot y = -x$ , where $a_0,a_1,a_2 \in \Bbb R \text{ and } a_2 \ne 0$ ,It has no isolated periodic orbits.

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Hope this isn't a duplicate.

I was trying to solve the following problem,

> Consider the following non-linear system : $$ \dot x = y-a_0-a_1 x - a_2 x^2$$
>   $$\dot y = -x$$ , where $a_0,a_1,a_2 \in \Bbb R \text{ and } a_2 \ne 0$ . Then prove that it has no isolated periodic orbits.

My attempt :

I considered the associated Linear system at the origin i.e.

$$Df(0) = \begin{bmatrix} -a_1 &  1 \cr -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

And then considering the eigenvalues I ended up having$$\lambda = \frac{-a_1 \pm \sqrt{{a_1}^2 -4}}{2}$$  and 3 cases : (i) ${a_1}^2 > 4$ , (ii) ${a_1}^2=4$ i.e. $a_1 = \pm 2$ and (iii) ${a_1}^2 < 4$ .

$(ii) \implies$ it (the Linear system) is either a stable or unstable node.

$(iii) \implies$ it is a center .

$(i) \implies$ it is either a stable node or an unstable node or a saddle.

All the observations $(i),(ii),(iii)$ are the expected behaviour of the Linear system at the origin $Df(0)$ .

Am I on the right track ? What do I have to do next ?

The fact that the origin is the only critical point of the non-linear system, would it help me to argue?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: No, I don't think that you are on the right path.  Linearizing the system at any equilibrium can give you at most information about the behavior near that equilibrium.  Do you know [Bendixson–Dulac theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem)?

Comment: @user539887 Would you kindly consider posting an answer

Comment: "Would you kindly consider posting an answer" Why not answer @user539887's question first?

Comment: @user539887 yes, but if you kindly explain your points in a bit more details, it will be extremely helpful.

Comment: It appears to me that, under your general assumptions, it is very hard to find a Dulac function (see the material linked in my previous answer; I may be wrong, of course).  On the other hand, the Bendixson-Dulac criterion excludes periodic orbits, while you are interested in the nonexistence of limit cycles.  [Hamiltonian systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_system) can have periodic orbits but cannot have limit cycles.  However, your system does not, in general, look like Hamiltonian.

Comment: @user539887 While this system doesn't look like Hamiltonian, when $a_1 =0$ it is [reversible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577274/formal-proof-of-lyapunov-stability/1577548#1577548): if $(\tilde x (t), \tilde y (t))$ is a solution of a system, then $(-\tilde x(-t), \tilde y(-t))$ is also a solution. This means that an equilibrium with purely imaginary eigenvalues is truly a center and there exists a continuum of periodic orbits around it. So, the formulation of the problem is pretty misleading and I agree that a clarification is needed.

Comment: @Evgeny I have solved the problem for $a_1=0$ and its pretty easy. My problem is when the question is more general say for arbitrary 2 degree polynomial!

Comment: @ThatIs The point is that you should clarify your question as much as possible if you want others to help you. You haven't said before that you already solved case $a_1 = 0$, so we can't telepathically know that you did it.

Comment: @Evgeny I'm trying to answer the question for a general 2 degree polynomial. What isn't clear about it?

Comment: @ThatIs What you have already did, that is what is unclear.